# Контекстное меню выделенного текста

Tags: java, android

Наткнулся на статью где рассказывалось про дополнительные пункты в контекстном меню при выделении текста. 
Код следующий

```
   textView.setTextIsSelectable(true);

editText.setCustomInsertionActionModeCallback(actionModeCallback);
```

Как можно сделать дополнительные пункты меню не в рамках одного приложения?

Comment: смущает фраза не в рамках одного приложения? поясните

Comment: В коде выше, как я понимаю, вешаеться кол бек на определенный текст вью. Возможно ли сделать дополнительный пункт в контекстном меню для всех приложений. Например выделить текст в браузере и отправить его в определенное активити по нажатию в контекстном меню.